# Не запускается программа PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qmainwindow

Решил я написать программу на PyQt5, проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь программу "подвести" под class, то она не работает (без класса все работает).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.setWindowTitle("Приложение EpicGames")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('resource/img/logo2.png'))
        self.setGeometry(525, 162, 1125, 807)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);')
        self.main_text = QLabel(self)
        self.main_text.setPixmap(QPixmap("resource/img/logo.png"))
        self.main_text.setScaledContents(True)
        self.main_text.setGeometry(80, 60, 41, 51)
        self.magazin = QPushButton(self)
        self.magazin.setFlat(True)
        self. magazin.setGeometry(15, 140, 162, 50)
        self.magazin.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/mag1.jpg) }
                QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/mag0.png) }
                QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/mag2.jpg) }
                """)
        self.bibl = QPushButton(self)
        self.bibl.setFlat(True)
        self.bibl.setGeometry(15, 192, 162, 60)
        self.bibl.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/bibl1.png) }
                QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/bibl0.png) }
                QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/bibl2.png) }
                """)
        self.un = QPushButton(self)
        self.un.setFlat(True)
        self.un.setGeometry(15, 255, 162, 55)
        self.un.setStyleSheet("""
                    QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/un1.png) }
                    QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/un0.png) }
                    QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/un2.png) }
                    """)
        self.poisk = QTextEdit(self)
        self.poisk.setGeometry(210, 60, 181, 31)
        self.poisk.setPlaceholderText("Поиск")
        self.poisk.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(84, 84, 84);\n"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.nov = QLabel(self)
        self.nov.setGeometry(470, 70, 61, 16)
        self.nov.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.nov.setText("Новости >")
        self.ic = QPushButton(self)
        self.c.setFlat(True)
        self.ic.setGeometry(1000, 60, 42, 42)
        self.ic.setStyleSheet("""
                       QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/ic1.png) }
                       QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/ic0.png) }
                       QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/ic2.png) }
                       """)
        self.raspr = QPushButton(self)
        self.raspr.setGeometry(220, 140, 672, 376)
        self.raspr.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(resource/img/123.png) stretch;")
        self.de = QPushButton(self)
        self.de.setGeometry(920, 140, 167, 50)
        self.de.setFlat(True)
        self.de.setStyleSheet("""
                          QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/iiic1.png) }
                          QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/iiic0.png) }
                          QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/iiic1.png) }
                          """)
        self.gov = QPushButton(self)
        self.gov.setGeometry(220, 500, 866, 287)
        self.gov.setFlat(True)
        self.gov.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(resource/img/gov.png) stretch;")
        self.gov.clicked.connect()
        self.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Так, а что именно не работает, какая ошибка?

Comment: @mazik7512 Не запускается программа

Comment: @S.Nick вообще-то программа запускается, то что в данном примере просто бездумно вставлен код и программа ничего не делает, это немного другое

Comment: @mazik7512 вот вы и ответили на свой вопрос из первого комментария.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Приложение EpicGames")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('resource/img/logo2.png'))
        self.setGeometry(525, 162, 1125, 807)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);')
        self.main_text = QLabel(self)
# --------------------------------------> vvvvvv                 установите свое
        self.main_text.setPixmap(QPixmap("Ok.png"))
        self.main_text.setScaledContents(True)
        self.main_text.setGeometry(80, 60, 41, 51)
        self.magazin = QPushButton(self)
        self.magazin.setFlat(True)
        self. magazin.setGeometry(15, 140, 162, 50)
        self.magazin.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/mag1.jpg) }
                QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/mag0.png) }
                QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/mag2.jpg) }
                """)
        self.bibl = QPushButton(self)
        self.bibl.setFlat(True)
        self.bibl.setGeometry(15, 192, 162, 60)
        self.bibl.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/bibl1.png) }
                QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/bibl0.png) }
                QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/bibl2.png) }
                """)
        self.un = QPushButton(self)
        self.un.setFlat(True)
        self.un.setGeometry(15, 255, 162, 55)
        self.un.setStyleSheet("""
                    QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/un1.png) }
                    QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/un0.png) }
                    QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/un2.png) }
                    """)
        self.poisk = QTextEdit(self)
        self.poisk.setGeometry(210, 60, 181, 31)
        self.poisk.setPlaceholderText("Поиск")
        self.poisk.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(84, 84, 84);\n"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.nov = QLabel(self)
        self.nov.setGeometry(470, 70, 61, 16)
        self.nov.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.nov.setText("Новости >")
        self.ic = QPushButton(self)
# ---------> vv       
        self.ic.setFlat(True)
        
        
        self.ic.setGeometry(1000, 60, 42, 42)
        self.ic.setStyleSheet("""
                       QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/ic1.png) }
                       QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/ic0.png) }
                       QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/ic2.png) }
                       """)
        self.raspr = QPushButton(self)
        self.raspr.setGeometry(220, 140, 672, 376)
        self.raspr.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(resource/img/123.png) stretch;")
        self.de = QPushButton(self)
        self.de.setGeometry(920, 140, 167, 50)
        self.de.setFlat(True)
        self.de.setStyleSheet("""
                          QPushButton:hover { background-image: url(resource/img/iiic1.png) }
                          QPushButton:!hover { background-image: url(resource/img/iiic0.png) }
                          QPushButton:pressed { background-image: url(resource/img/iiic1.png) }
                          """)
        self.gov = QPushButton(self)
# -------------------------> vvvvvvvv                      установите свое
        self.gov.setGeometry(150, 380, 866, 287)
        self.gov.setFlat(True)
# ----------------------------------------------> vvvvvvv установите свое
        self.gov.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(boy.jpg) stretch;")
        

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()  
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое, не подскажите, что вы изменили?

Comment: @simima добавил в самом конце пять строк. удалив некоторые из них из класса. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour